# Sort related entities in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sorting, core-data

I have two entities in my core data model. Author and Book. An author can have many books.
This is the part I've got sorted out. It's all working.

Now I'd like to fetch my authors in alphabetical order:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Author" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

No problems so far. But now I would like to fetch all the author's books, ordered by release date.
When I fetch the author's books using the following line of code …

```
self.selectedAuthor.books.allObjects
```

… the order of books seems to be completely random.

**My question:**

How can sort an object's related entities when fetching them from the core data, so that every time I use `self.selectedAuthor.books.allObjects`, all books are ordered by (for example) release date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method `- (NSArray *)booksSortedByDate;` to the Author class interface and in the implementation write code like this:

```
- (NSArray *)booksSortedByDate {
    return [self.books.allObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"releaseDate" ascending:YES]]];
}
```

Comment: The other answer, given by Martin R, seems to be the right way to handle this, but your answer was most fitting to my situation. So thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The to-many relationship `books` is represented by an `NSSet`, which is an
*unordered* collection. You can either

- Get the array of all books `self.selectedAuthor.books.allObjects` as you did,
  and then sort this array in memory,

or

- Execute a fetch request on the `Book` entity with the predicate

  ```
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author = %@", self.selectedAuthor]
  ```

  to get only books of that author, and add a sort descriptor to the fetch request
  to get the books sorted by release date.

Comment: Is there a way to do the second approach if a Book can have more than 1 author?